# How to start a process (or Kafka to be specific) on remote host with Ansible Playbook

Tags: apache-kafka, ansible

How to start Zookeeper and Kafka broker on remote target with Ansible Playbook.

Following commands work fine locally.

Start Zookeeper:
`cd /opt/kafka`
`./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`

Start Kafka Broker: (setting 2 env variables while starting)
`JMX_PORT="5555" KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xms500M -Xmx550M" ./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the modules [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html), [command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html)

Using [command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html), I think something like that should work:

```
- name: Start Zookeeper
  command:
    cmd:  ./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
    chdir:  /opt/kafka

- name: Start Kafka broker
  command:
    cmd: 'JMX_PORT="5555" KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xms500M -Xmx550M" ./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties'
    chdir: /opt/kafka
```

Comment: command module works but the Playbook execution doesn't end; it hangs as the script runs in foreground and shows zookeeper logs on the screen. When I try following, I get error saying "msg": "non-zero return code"

`- name: Start Zookeeper
  command:
    cmd: nohup ./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties > logs/zookpeer.logs 2>&1 &
    chdir:  /opt/kafka`

Comment: @Avinash You need to pass `-daemon` flag to run the servers in the background

Comment: Using `shell` or `command` for this can work but is bad practice (see @OneCricketeer answer regarding registering a service). Using `raw` in this situation is definitely evil.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend creating a systemd service file that you can start/stop appropriately using the Ansible `service` module.

Confluent offers `cp-ansible` repo that you can either copy from, or use directly to install a Kafka + Zookeeper cluster (and more)